Resolving undefined symbol: configDir error after migrating to 64-bit architecture and RedHat 7
I recently migrated a large C++ project from a 32-bit architecture running on RedHat 6 to a 64-bit architecture on RedHat 7. After the migration, I encountered a runtime error
undefined symbol: configDir
related to an extern variable used across multiple files and possibly shared libraries. The variable is defined and used as follows:
// Definition in config/ConfigManager.C and config/ConfigBackup.C
char *configDir;
configDir = getcwd(0, 64);
if (configDir == 0) {
    configDir = ::getenv("PWD");
}

// Usage in other files like app/network/transport/com/linkmanager.c
extern char *configDir;
key_t key = ftok(configDir, SOME_CONSTANT);

This setup worked without issues on the 32 bit system. Has there been a change in how extern variables are handled between these versions of RedHat, or could this be an issue related to differences in handling of shared libraries or linking in the 64-bit environment?
Also, I tried using attribute((visibility("default"))) but it did not work.

No, this should just work. Show the full linker command line. Also, is your extern declaration tagged with extern "C" ?

@Botje Hi, thanks I will make sure to add what you said. The extern "C" might just work in my case I think, because I didn't use it

char *configDir; Is this your real code? If it's at the file level, if (configDir == 0) { gives a compilatiuon error. If it's at a block level, configDir has a block scope and is unrelated to the extern one. "Definition in ... and ... " Now that could be a violation of the one definition rule.
